# shell: "can't shift that many" error

Tags: shell

The following script works fine in one of my machines, printing `1` then `2`:

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "1"
shift
echo "2"
```

On another machine, however, it produces the following output:

```
1
./script.sh: 4: shift: can't shift that many
```

`man shift` does not help (`No manual entry for shift`).

What is that error, why is it happening, and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**What is `shift`:** it is a shell built-in that works as follows (adapted from [TLDP](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_07.html)):

> The shift command takes one argument, a number (if not present, it is assumed to be 1). The positional parameters (e.g. command arguments) are shifted to the left by this number, N. The positional parameters from N+1 to $# are renamed to variable names from $1 to $# - N+1.

Often you make a loop in which you process one or more arguments, then you call shift to "forget" them and loop again to process the following ones.

**Error cause:**
The error comes from the fact that some shells (but not all) detect when there are not enough arguments for `shift`. In particular, `dash` considers it a fatal error.

**Possible solutions:**

- Test if there are enough remaining arguments: `if [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; then shift; fi`
- Add a conditional argument: `shift $(( $# > 0 ? 1 : 0 ))`

Comment: Just stumbled across this when I had the same problem. Thanks for posting this Q&A! You can also accept your own answer (that's considered perfectly *acceptable*, ba-dum-tss). (There's a two-day delay before you can accept your own answer, but I think it's safe to say that's elapsed by now.) ;)

Comment: `let $# && shift` aka `(( $# )) && shift` is another form of conditionally doing a shift. If i understand it correctly, the double parenthesis (or: two parentheses, or: two round brackets) are the same as the command `let` which allows for arithmetic evaluation. And `let 0` (or: `(( 0 ))`) evaluates to a non-zero exit.

Comment: Or maybe a bit different.. The POSIX-version seems to be `test $(( $# )) && shift` as `((`& `let` seem not to be in the standard. perhaps relevant: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2219 .